# ListView.builder inside futurebuilder inside Listview

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanted to to make my home page scrollable i mean i want to scroll everthing on the body so i made a list view and inside the list view there are other widgets and under those widgets i want to show a future builder that has another listview.builder in it but i dont want it to be scrolled alone i want it to be scrolled with the other widgets in the home screen

this is my home screen body:

```
 body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Search(),
            FeaturedProducts(),
            OnSaleProducts(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

`OnSaleProducts()` is the widget that has a futurebuilder in it this is the code

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: FutureBuilder(
            future: getOnSaleProduct(),
            builder: (_, snapshot){
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 4,
                    itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                      return Column(
                      );
                    });
              }else return ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  itemCount: 9,
                  itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                    return InkWell(child: ProductCard(name: "new", price: 123, picture: '', onSale: true));
                  });
            }));
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you should not use a ListView inside OnSalesProduct() but a simple Column!

```
Column(children: List.generate(count, (int index) => widget(index))
```

Comment: where do i put my products card

Comment: Replace widget(index) with InkWell(child: ProductCard(name: "new $index", price: 123, picture: '', onSale: true))

Answer (score 0):

**Hopefully, what you are trying to know:**

1. Scroll everthing on the body
2. Inside the scrollable view, want to show a future builder that has
   another listview.builder
3. Don't want it to be scrolled alone it to be scrolled with the other
   widgets in the home screen

**Let's try this code, hopefully you will get your answerers and solution together:**

```
SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Search(),
            FeaturedProducts(),
            OnSaleProducts(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

**Now do this for OnSaleProducts() widget:**

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height, // better for fixed size 
      width: double.infinity,
      child: FutureBuilder<PopularFoodList>(
              future: getOnSaleProduct(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      itemCount: 9,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                         var item = snapshot.data[index]; // snapshot.data.anotherProperty[index]; // If your model has anotherProperty
                         return InkWell(child: ProductCard(name: item.name, price: item.price, picture: '', onSale: true));
                      });
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Center(child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()));
                }
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              })

    );
  }
```